# R no puede cargar una imagen

Tags: rstudio

Cuando cargo un programa (BEAR) que tiene imágenes, aparece el siguiente mensaje

> """"Error in readPNG(system.file("img", "bear_logo-2016.png", package = "bear")""""

No sé cómo resolverlo, alguien tiene idea de qué ocurre?

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código que estás ejecutando.